# Jquery After() unless

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an ecommerce site which is using a theme that adds tags alpha and omega to divs to help apply code for rows IE alpha is the first product in a row and omega is the last.

However I have added a timer on products that applied a class myproduct-1 to it when the timer is expired. This adds `display: none !important` styling to the product.

I originally wanted to add a tag `<br class="clear">`after an element where a the `<div class="omega">` which looks like this:

`$( ".omega" ).after("<br class='clear'/>" );` which works perfectly

However I have discovered that, though normally I want to do this on omega, when alpha is hidden I want to add this to alpha instead. Not really sure how to check for that and only add it to omega at the correct time.

here is an example of one of the products (it has the myproduct-1 class and alpha):

```
<div class="myproducts-1 eight columns alpha thumbnail even" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">





  <a href="/collection/product" itemprop="url">
    <div class="relative product_image">
      <img />


        <span data-fancybox-href="#product-783878980" class="quick_shop ss-icon" data-gallery="product-783878980-gallery">
          +
        </span>

    </div>

    <div class="info">           
      <span class="title" itemprop="name">Product</span>


        <span class="price " itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">



                <span itemprop="price">$ 27.00</span>



        </span>

<div id="productTimer-783878980" class="is-countdown"><div class="clearall"></div><div class="mySection"><div class="timerbox">00</div><div class="timerText">Days</div></div><div class="mySection"><div class="timerbox">00</div><div class="timerText">Hours</div></div><div class="mySection"><div class="timerbox">00</div><div class="timerText">Min</div></div><div class="mySection"><div class="timerbox">00</div><div class="timerText">Sec</div></div><div class="clearall"></div></div>
```

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you showed your HTML.

Comment: use the `:hidden` in your selector to match for the hidden element, e.g. `.alpha:hidden`

Comment: instead of adding elements to clear the floats, why not just add a class instead to clear the floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if($('.alpha').is(':hidden')) {
  $( ".alpha" ).after("<br class='clear'/>" );
} else {
  $( ".omega" ).after("<br class='clear'/>" );
}
```